# Batch replacement in Excel with macro

Tags: vba, excel

I found a piece of code that should do what I'm looking for but I'm running into an error I'm not sure how to resolve.

The code is below and the error is Compile Error: Expected List separator or

```
Sub multiFindandReplace()

Dim myList, myRange
Set myList = Sheets(“sheet1”).Range(“D1:E11”) ‘two column range with find/replace pairs
Set myRange = Sheets(“sheet1”).Range(“B1:B99”) ‘range to be searched and replace
For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole
Next cel

End Sub
```

I'm really new to macro's and vba so apologies if there's an obvious solution, but basically I have a bunch of ID strings (~300 per participant) that I'd like to replace with a simpler `SubjectID`.

I also have each ID string in a column next to the `SubID` (see below).

Ideally I'd like to just run a Macro that says "Replace any instance of Cell A1 (i.e. the first ID String) with B1 (i.e. the first `SubID`)"

```
ID String           Sub ID

R_RRdl3hwpEszOAO5     1

R_2DTiOiFDmERbIeP     2

R_1OHaghH1DCv8Rep     3

R_RwcKdPaKmX8De6Z     4

R_2rI62IyTK6rUHKu     5
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following Sub:

```
Sub ReplaceID()
    Dim maxRow As Integer
    maxRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A1:A" & maxRow).Value = Range("B1:B" & maxRow).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again for your assistance Alex! Unfortunately I'm not getting the code your kindly provided to run correctly - it is only replacing the first instance of each ID String with the subject ID - I am trying to replace 300 identical ID strings with a single subject ID (for multiple subject IDs - there are around 200 subject ID's and 6000ish ID Strings (but only 200 of them are unique). I really appreciate the help!

Comment: You are welcome. Frankly, I probably misinterpreted the business requirements, but it seems you already have found a solution. If it works for you, then it's just fine. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

you could try one of the following three macros

```
Option Explicit


Sub multiFindandReplace()

Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range

Set myList = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1:E11") 'two column range with find/replace pairs
Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B99") 'range to be searched and replace

With myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    With .Offset(, 1)
        .FormulaR1C1 = "=match(RC[-1]," & myList.Columns(1).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",0)"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=index(" & myList.Columns(2).Address(, , xlR1C1) & ",RC[+1])"
    .Value = .Value
    .Offset(, 1).ClearContents
End With

End Sub


Sub multiFindandReplace2()

Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, cell As Range, fnd As Range

Set myList = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1:E11") 'two column range with find/replace pairs
Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B99") 'range to be searched and replace

For Each cell In myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    cell.Value = myList.Cells(myList.Columns(1).Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True).Row, 2)
Next cell
End Sub


Sub multiFindandReplace3()

Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, cell As Range, fnd As Range

Set myList = Sheets("sheet1").Range("D1:E11") 'two column range with find/replace pairs
Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("B1:B99") 'range to be searched and replace

For Each cell In myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set fnd = myList.Columns(1).Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then cell.Value = myList.Cells(fnd.Row, 2)
Next cell
End Sub
```

the first one being by far the fastest in my tests , but it uses a "helper" column (one left of `myRange`) you must ensure there are no data in (otherwise it's easy to change)

the other two macros can be possibly faster then they are by setting `Application.ScreenUpdating=False` at the beginning and then setting it back  `Application.ScreenUpdating=True` right before the end)

the last one being the same as the second except for a little error handling treatment